# Laravel Passport - Validar token dentro de Controlador

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando validar si el usuario esta autenticado dentro del controlador, yo se que puedo hacerlo directamente en rutas, pero este no es el caso ya que debe ser una ruta publica sin necesidad de ningún middleware.

```
public function share(Request $request){
       $token = $request->header('Authorization');
```

De esta manera estoy obteniendo el token, pero... utilizando passport, como puedo traer la información del usuario, algo como lo siguiente(logica de prueba solamente):

```
$user User::where('token', $token)->first()
```

¿Como puedo verificar el usuario autenticado desde el controlador?

Answer (score 1):

He probado este código y me funcionó bien.

```
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory;

...

public function __construct(ResourceServer $server)
{
    $this->server = $server;
}

...

public function doSomething()
{
    $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

    try {
        $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
    } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
        throw new AuthenticationException;
    }

    $user = User::find($psr->getAttribute('oauth_user_id'));

    return $user;
}
```

[Referencia](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/175#issuecomment-260843859)

Saludos

Comment: Lo checo y te aviso!.